# How do I append a child to all the nodes with the specified classname using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, appendchild, getelementsbyclassname

```
var menuheader = document.createElement("li"); 
document.getElementsByClassName("subMenu").appendChild(menuheader);
```

Above is the code snippet. I get this error:

```
firebug: TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).appendChild is not a function
```

Comment: Because `getElementsByClassName()` returns nodeList! Try `document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0].appendChild` to target first-element in list!

Comment: I recommend to read the MDN documentation before you use any DOM methods you are not familiar with. Here is the one for `getElementsByClassName`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
var menuheader = document.createElement("li");// creates main menu to which below submenu should be added. 
var submenus=document.getElementsByClassName("subMenu"); //gives an array so you cannot append child to that.

   for(int i=0;i<submenus.length;i++){
   menuheader.appendChild(submenus[i]);

  }
```

From your code it seems that you are doing reverse that is adding mainmenu to submenu which again.

```
  document.createElement("li"); //create a main menu say Services
```

Services

So I need to add submenu to above element so that it should look like

Services

->Non billable Service

->I.T service

->Billable Service

Comment: Thanks Shoaib thats what i was looking for a "for loop", as this method returns a node list.